# PyGame code works in terminal but not in window

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make letters in a sentence appear letter by letter. I tested it by simply printing the letters in the terminal, and it worked. I tried to then put it on the screen and what it does is bizzare. It waits for the terminal to finish printing *then* puts all of the letters on the screen at the same time. I am trying to use "ptext" which I found at https://github.com/cosmologicon/pygame-text When printing "letter" it outputs *exactly* what I want in the terminal, then when trying to do the same thing using ptext it does not work. Immediately after the text finishes printing, the window crashes.

Code can be seen below:

```
    for letter in dialogue:
        letterx += 20
        sleep(0.2)
        print(letter)
        ptext.draw(letter, (letterx, 100), fontname="text/dialogue.ttf", fontsize=30)
```

Full code can be found at my [Github repository.](https://github.com/LucasGlennieOC/classroom) Any help is greatly appreciated! :D

Comment: pygame draws all objects in buffer and it needs `flip()` to display buffer. if you don't use `flip()` after every letter then it will not display it char by char but first it will draw all chars in buffer and later it will display all in one moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of your loop, immediately after the `ptext.draw`, just add:

```
        pygame.display.update()
```

That's all it takes.  Of course, that still leaves your GUI tied up the whole time.  Fixing that will require you to use `.after`, so you draw the next letter, then get a callback to draw the next letter, and so on.